# Using GIT, how do I pull from a remote system a directory and its files but not its descendant folders

Tags: git

I'm trying to figure out how to just for now to pull a directory that we have on a server but only the specific folder and the files that are in it. I need to ignore they subdirectories that are inside of it because someone had accidentally place a GB of data in it so I keep getting a 504 timeout issue. Person is not in today and I don't have rights to alter the structure right now.

So I only want to pull the specified directory and all of the files that are in that directory.

I saw some documentation on the gitignore but that appears to be to ignore files that are on my system.

Any guidance on this?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with git. There are ways to check out a sub-tree, like sparse checkout, but checking out one directory and ignoring its children, I don't believe git knows how to do that.

Comment: Thank you Dan for the input.

Comment: For all the rave that GIT gets, I would expect this function to be there. I'm sure it has to be. In subversion I am able to specify in a folder specific folders within the directory tree that I wish to pull, in turn ignoring the others. Granted the team has fixed the tree structure where this is not a problem now, but in the future I would like to know how to control what I pull instead of pulling everything.